ImportError: cannot import name 'packaging' from 'pkg_resources' when trying to install causal_conv1d
I was trying to install "causal_conv1d" using:
pip install --no-cache-dir  -t /scratch/ahmed/lib  causal_conv1d==1.0.0

The error I got is:
Collecting causal_conv1d==1.0.0
  Downloading causal_conv1d-1.0.0.tar.gz (6.4 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-9i0wsv2k/causal-conv1d_fc0a21267f664102adca1aa336c93106/setup.py", line 19, in <module>
          from torch.utils.cpp_extension import (
        File "/scratch/ahmed/lib/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 28, in <module>
          from pkg_resources import packaging  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      ImportError: cannot import name 'packaging' from 'pkg_resources' (/scratch/ahmed/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py)
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.


Why is pip importing a file from your /scratch mount? Have you changed your PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Yes ... I updated the full pip command. i'm sorry for the confusion @darthbith

So the error is because pkg_resources is not installed in the isolated build environment. You might need to add the --no-build-isolation (I think that's the flag) to your pip line

I tried but got: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg_resources (from versions: none) @darthbith

I don't know the exact problem, but it seems this problem happened when I used two directories for Python "lib": one was the default Anaconda lib, and I had another separate one. The problem disappeared when I used only the default Anaconda lib.
It works fine now.

This seems to be a problem with the latest version of setuptools. Similar reportings have been done in github issues and the solution that worked for me was to specify the setuptools version to 69.5.1, so for example:
pip install setuptools==69.5.1

In your case, you should run this command before trying to install causal_conv1d.
I had the same issue in a docker container and similarly, I added a RUN command to install that particular version of setuptools.

Reverting to setuptools==69.5.1 solved the issue for me on another package installation, thanks!

For torchvision, this solution worked for me.

This worked for me for mmcv-1.38. There were similar reportings under github for setuptools. When in doubt, just revert to previous versions. Hope it will fixed soon.
